# How to convert 1D byte array to 2D byte array which holds a bitmap?

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, arrays

I have already used the LockBits and UnlockBits functions and takes the byte array of a Image into a 1D array. (considering only the black and white/binarized images)

Is there any way of taking it to a 2D array (of the size image height and width)? so i can wirte the array into a ".txt" file and view it?

The code i have used to take the image into 1D array is as below:

```
Public void function(Bitmap image){
{
byte[] arr1D;
byte[] arr2D;

BitmapData data = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, img_w, img_h), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, image.PixelFormat);
            try
            {
                IntPtr ptr = data.Scan0;
                int bytes = Math.Abs(data.Stride) * image.Height;
                byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
                arr1D = rgbValues;
                Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
            }
            finally
            {
                image.UnlockBits(data);
            }
}
```

Since the image is binary, the values of the Byte array is from only 255 and 0.

Instead of extracting the entire image to a 1D array, is there any method/code where i can extract pixel row by row to a 2D array, Where i can write it to a text file and see later on?

*Programming Language : **C#***

example: (if the value 255 is replaced with 1)

*result output:*
1D array: (6px X 6px image)

```
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
```

*expected output:*
2D array: (6px X 6px image)

```
0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 0
```

**Can someone please help me with the code for it in C#?**

Comment: You can write a 1D array to a file in N-dimensions; it's just a matter of viewing them. Write W entries the first line, then add a newline, then write W entries the next line and so on until H lines are written. The total number of written entries is W*H (or the size of the 1D array).

Comment: @user2246674 : Will you be able to type the code snippet for me, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple function that takes a 1d int array and the size of each row you want the data split up into and returns a 2d array.

```
public int[,] ConvertArray(int[] Input, int size)
{
    int[,] Output = new int[(int)(Input.Length/size),size];
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\OutFile.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.Length; i += size)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            Output[(int)(i / size), j] = Input[i + j];
            sw.Write(Input[i + j]);
        }
        sw.WriteLine("");
    }
    sw.Close();
    return Output;
}
```

I didn't add any validation to make sure the input array is exactly divisible by the size, if necessary you'll need to add that.

I did add code to write the data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple.

```java
private int[][] conver1dTo2d(int[] arr, int w, int h){
        int[][] answer = new int[h][w];
        for(int i = 0 ; i<arr.length; i++){
            answer[i/w][i%w] = arr[i];
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

or

```java
private int[][] conver1dTo2d(int[] arr, int rowSize){
        int[][] answer = new int[arr.length/rowsize][rowSize];
        for(int i = 0 ; i<arr.length; i++){
            answer[i/rowSize][i%rowSize] = arr[i];
        }
        return answer;
    }
```