# Convert image to array 2d

Tags: c#, .net, image

I'm need to convert an image to 2D array but I don't know how. I managed to convert it into 1D array so far.

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
     imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
     return ms.ToArray();
} 
Image image = Image.FromFile("c:\\p01.png");
byte[] mm = imageToByteArray(image);
```

Comment: _Please do not put -1_ If you ask a question in a good way, believe me nobody don't. Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: You can use a BitMap!

Comment: ok Th's Question i don't how solve problem and i'm search to the's question and no one solve Th's proplem .

Comment: i'm co't how using BitMap to solve  Th's proplem

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the Save function doesn't save just the image pixels data but also the bitmap header info, like width , height, etc. so the array you get contains extra info you don't want

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to this question: [How to convert 1D byte array to 2D byte array which holds a bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387509/how-to-convert-1d-byte-array-to-2d-byte-array-which-holds-a-bitmap)

Basically, you want to pass `image.Width` to the `ConvertArray` function mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17388835/207661) that converts 1D array to 2D array.

Comment: Th's the problem i don't know how Width

Comment: You are using System.Drawing.Image class in your example. There is Image.Width property to get width of the image. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.width(v=vs.110).aspx